# Add custom http header in RedirectView

Tags: python, django, http-headers, django-class-based-views

I want to add the http header but it does not work.
I'm trying to test solve by using the print, but it appears nothing

This is my code but not works:

```
class MyRedirectView(RedirectView):

    def head(self, *args, **kwargs):
        response = HttpResponse()
        response['X-Robots-Tag'] = 'noindex'
        print('TEST')
        return response
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you have done here is to override the `head` method. Which is only used when a HTTP request of the type HEAD is made to your url. You should override the `get` method or better still the dispatch method instead.

```
class MyRedirectView(RedirectView):

    def dispatch(self, *args, **kwargs):
        response = super(MyRedirectView,self).dispatch(*args, **kwargs)
        response['X-Robots-Tag'] = 'noindex'
        print('TEST LOL')
        return response
```

Comment: glad to have been of help